# The requested module '@chakra-ui/react' does not provide an export named 'Box' while executing test cases

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to write test cases for a component written with @chakra-ui/react. The component is rendered in the desired way but the test case is failing with an error `The requested module '@chakra-ui/react' does not provide an export named 'Box'`.

This is how my component looks like

```
import {Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';

const Sample = () => {
    return (
        <Box>This is a simple Box</Box>
    );
};

export default Sample;
```

I am using react-testing-library for writing test cases. This is how I have written my test case

```
import React from "react"
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import Sample from "./Sample"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";



describe("<EntitySearch/>",()=>{
    it("Renders <Sample/> Component",()=>{
        const {getByText}=render(<Sample/>);       
        expect(getByText(/Entity/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    })
})
```

This is my jestConfig

```
{
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    "testEnvironment":"jest-environment-jsdom",
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts','.tsx'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
    },
    transform: {
      // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
      // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
      '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
        'ts-jest',
        {
          useESM: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  };
```

I tried changing the importing components from @chakra-ui/ instead and test cases were passing with this change but the package does not contain all the required components as in @chakra-ui/react